# Minor upgrade an MSI installed as a component of a Wix burn installer

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

I have a product that has 8 installers.
Each installer is a component of a single burn bundle.
The total bundle size is 300MB

One of the installers in the bundle is a 20MB msi, which is the core of the product.
The other 280MB of the bundle are dependencies of the product.
I would prefer to ship updates to the product as 20MB packages (or smaller patches), rather than require that a 300MB installer is downloaded every time we ship an update.

My question is twofold:

1. Can an msi package that was installed as part of a burn bundle be updated independently of the burn bundle?
2. Would uninstall/repair of the burn bundle be broken if I did this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new bundle and give it a patch RelatedBundle entry of the upgrade code of the original bundle. Burn knows how to handle patch bundles as "children" of the original bundle.

Comment: Thanks Bob. I won't have time to try this for a week or so, could you tell me what the build outputs I should expect to get when I build v2 of the product? I'm guessing a 300MB installer for new installs) + a patch file that can be used to upgrade V1. Correct?

Comment: You can create a new version of your existing bundle and it will handle upgrading the old version. Or you can additionally create a patch bundle that contains only updates.